# Unknown module(s) in QT: quick

Tags: qt, qt-quick, qt6

I'm trying to run QtQuick App for the first time, but when I run the default code I get this error (Unknown module(s) in QT: quick). I'm on Ubuntu running QT 6, I've already tried installing qtdeclarative5-dev but it doesn't help.
I would appreciate any help [screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtVs0.png)

Comment: You're not running program, you're running qmake. `qtdeclarative5-dev` is Qt5 dev module, it has no effect on Qt6 install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out i just needed to install qt6-declarative-dev